# Facelets: need only an <ui:define> tag of a page

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

Okay, to include a page in another page I need `<ui:include src="pageName"/>` tag. But if i want to include only a portion of a page?

Let me explain: 
I have a template that has the tag `<ui:insert name="body"/>` and other `<ui:insert.../>` tags.
A page, List.xhtml, uses this template and, of course, fills up ALL the template tags. Now, in another page, named Create.xhtml (that uses the same template), at a certain point, i want to put ONLY the body tag content of List.xhtml, not other tags. Is it possible?

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

template.xhtml:

```
......

<ui:insert name="body"/>

......
```

List.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns=....... template="/template.xhtml">

..............

     <ui:define name="body">

          <ui:include src="ListContent.xhtml"/>

     </ui:define>

..............

</ui:composition>
```

ListContent.xhtml

```
<ui:component xmlns....>

     Content I can reuse in other pages different by List.xhtml 
     (without see List.xhtml entire content, which is the scope of this question),
     simply writing "<ui:include src="ListContent.xhtml"/>" in the target page code.

</ui:component>
```

Hope can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest might be to break out the body section of your List.xhtml into its own `<ui:composition>`. Then you can re-use it in with `<ui:decorate>` in the pages where you need it. This would be the "template" way of doing it.

Alternativly, you can create a `<ui:component>` out of the body section. This would be the "component" way of doing it. Both should achieve the same basic goal you have, but composition/decorate might be simpler.

UPDATE
Example (See also [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-decorate.html)).

commonBody.xhtml

```
...
<ui:composition>
<p>This is some common body.</p>
<p><ui:insert name="dynamicBody" /></p>
</ui:composition>
```

List.xhtml

```
...
<body>
<h1>This is the List.xhtml</h1>
<ui:decorate template="commonBody.xhtml">
<ui:define name="dynamicBody">Body of List.xhtml</ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
</body>
...
```

Would output something like

```
...
<body>
<h1>This is the List.xhtml</h1>
<p>This is some common body.</p>
<p>Body of List.xhtml</p>
</body>
...
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you say, can you write an example, please?

Comment: Yeah now I understand, quite simple! Thank you. Also, I discovered another method, experimenting with components, see below.